# A family has $8$ kids. What is the probability that at least $4$ of them are boys?

Tags: probability, statistics

For exactly $4$ boys, and $4$ girls I got $70/256$, but I'm not sure how *at least* $4$ boys change the scenario here.

Comment: you got the probability of 4 boys. Now add in the probability of 5 boys, the probability of 6 boys, 7 and 8. In all those events (and only those events) there are at least 4 boys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the probability of exactly 4 boys.  If that doesn't happen, then the probability of more than four is equal to the probability of less than four.  So divide the probability of "not four" by two and add it to "exactly four".  I get

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{256-70}{256}+\frac{70}{256} =  \frac{163}{256}$$